# what is meaning of using {$} {$} in tabular environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am reading the Tug manual
following link 
https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-3/tb90hoeppner.pdf
has example in section 2.1 using `array`. Augmented here to make it compilable "out of the box":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}%
   {>{\ttfamily\char`\\}c>{$}c<{$}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Command} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Symbol}\\
\hline
alpha & \alpha\\
beta & \beta\\
gamma & \gamma
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to know what is meant by

- `>{$}c<{$}` in the program.
- what is meant by `%` in front of    `\begin{tabular}`
- what is meant by  `>{\ttfamily\char‘\\}c`

based on my understanding I could infer that  `{>{\ttfamily\char‘\\}c` is probably adding a backslash to each text item,
further in the same document they have a paragraph which reads as follows

> command hooks from being applied for these cells. Another use of these
>   command hooks is typesetting paragraphs in narrow columns. LATEX
>   typesets these paragraphs left and right justified by default, but in
>   narrow columns it is often more appropriate to typeset them using
>   `\raggedright`.

I am not able to understand the meaning of raggedright in tabular environment. As what does this do?

Comment: It's not just `{$}`.  `>{...}` inserts the content of the braces at the beginning of the table cell; `<{...}` performs the insert at the end of the cell.  The `$` make this cell math mode.  The `%` says to ignore the end-line character, which ordinarily inserts a space, and run this line together with the following line.  It's not really needed here, but is "insurance"; it could be followed by a comment, which would be ignored.  `\raggedright` says that, if the content of a "paragraph" cell takes up more than one line, don't stretch lines to justify them; this generally looks much nicer.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing the code snippet you posted.

Comment: ok to have the symbols  alpha beta gama appear as symbol and not text they have used $ to insert it and as you mention it is not just {$} it is used as >{...} and <{...} to have math mode in each cell when they have \alpha in 2nd column it will be going as $\alpha$ and hence it gets translated to symbolic value,if  I understand it correctly.

Comment: please read the manuals of the packages you are using. That `$` example is in the second page of the `array` manual. (`texdoc array`)  You are asking a _lot_ of table questions but you can do some background reading first.

Comment: I am using Windows 10,I dont know where to find texdoc array in windows command prompt

Comment: @koeradoera just type it on the commandline or your editor might have a help menu or use the online version https://texdoc.net/pkg/array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation `>{tokens}c` means that every cell in that column will be preceded by `tokens`; similarly, `c<{tokens}` tells TeX to append `tokens` to the cell's contents.

Thus `>{$}c<{$}` means that the contents of the cell will be surrounded by `$...$`, so typeset in math mode.

In your example `\alpha` will be seen as `$\alpha$` and the same for the other cells in the second column.

Any column specifier can be used, so also `l`, `r` and the others.

What about `\raggedright`? Suppose you want a column to be `p{4cm}`. Justification in such a narrow column would be complicated, so one can do

```
>{\raggedright}p{4cm}
```

and the contents of the cell will be typeset ragged right.

Remember to do `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}` if this is the last column of the table, because otherwise `\\` would not end the table row.

Answer (score 6):

Before I start addressing your questions, it's worth displaying the typeset table (screenshot taken from the TUGBoat article):

[image]

Observe that the contents of the left-hand column are typeset using a monospaced font and and that the contents of the right-hand column are three math symbols.

- What is meant by `>{$}c<{$}` [in the definition of the 2nd column of the `tabular` environment]?

  I trust you know that `c` means "centering" and that the `$` character, by itself, means "either open or close inline math mode".

  The `>{$}` and `<{$}` particles "sandwich" the column in a pair of `$` characters. What does that mean? Consider the first cell in the right-hand column (other than the header cell): it contains `\alpha`. Because `tabular` is a text-mode environment by default, TeX would surely complain about encountering `\alpha` while in text mode. But, because the column is not defined as `c` but as `>{$}c<{$}`, what TeX *actually* gets to work on is not `\alpha` but `$\alpha$` -- which is just fine.

  Why go to all this trouble, you may ask? Why not set `c` as the column type and type $\alpha$`,`$\beta$`, and $\gamma$` in the three cells in the second column? Well, it would work, but it would also entail typing lots more `$` symbols and creating needless code clutter.
- What is meant by `%` [after] `\begin{tabular}`?

  Again, I will assume that you know that `%` is TeX's comment-initiating character.

  My guess is that because the original article was typeset in two-column mode with fairly narrow columns, typesetting the directive

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily\char`\\}c>{$}c<{$}}
  ```

  on a single line would have exceeded the width of the column. Writing

  ```
  \begin{tabular}%
      {>{\ttfamily\char`\\}c>{$}c<{$}}
  ```

  achieves the exact same thing, but without exceeding the width of the column.
- What is meant by `>{\ttfamily\char‘\\}c`?

  As before, `c` means centering and `>{...}` means that `...` will get inserted immediately before each and every cell in that content (*unless* the column type is overridden via `\multicolumn`, as is done in the very first cell of the left-hand column). Here, `...` consists of two parts: `\ttfamily` and `\char‘\\`. The former switches to a monospaced ("teletype") font, and the latter literally typesets a backslash *character*. Thus, TeX typesets first a backslash character and then `alpha`, both using a monospaced font.

  Once more, you might be tempted to ask, "Why bother with creating a complicated column definition?" For sure, one *could* have obtained the exact same result by selecting `c` as the column type and inputting `\ttfamily\string\alpha`, `\ttfamily\string\beta`, and `\ttfamily\string\gamma` in the cells. I think it should be fairly obvious that there's a large payoff, not only in terms of sheer convenience but also in terms of code legibility, of changing `c` to

  ```
  >{\ttfamily\char`\\}c
  ```

  and inputting `alpha`, `beta`, and `gamma` instead.

  More generally, the whole point of the TeXBoat article is to demonstrate various possibilities of customizing the basic column types (`l`, `c`, `r` and `p`).
- I am not able to understand the meaning of raggedright in tabular environment.

  By default, TeX formats paragraphs so that they are (fully) justified. This matters for the `p` ("paragraph") column type. Justifying a paragraph in a way that's pleasing to the reader's eye becomes increasingly difficult to achieve as the paragraph width decreases. Once a paragraph is sufficiently narrow, it's better to switch to ragged-right mode, also known as flush-left mode.

  To switch a `p`-type column to ragged-right mode, write `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p`.

Comment: For coming to paragraph column type we use `p{...}` in the definition of \begin{tabular}{ } or something else ?I read many places it is used for vertical alignment. as given [here wikibooks table entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) they mention `p{'width'} paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top`

Comment: Nice explication of the TUGboat article.  Too bad the line breaking (maybe specific to my screen because of the width allotted to question/answer text) in the last paragraph has split the `>` from the `{...}` and its contents.

Comment: @koeradoera - The "vertical alignment" part refers exclusively to how the contents of a cell typeset in `p` mode are placed next to the cell whose contents are typeset, say, in `c` mode . The contents of a cell typeset in `p` mode often span more than 1 line. The `p` column type performs "top" (vertical) alignment, the `m` column type performs "middle" vertical alignment, and the `b` column type performs, you guessed it, "bottom" alignment.